# Limit $\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{a x+b} - 2}{x}$ equals to $\frac{5}{12}$

Tags: calculus, limits

A friend of mine asked this question to me. It seems it's from Stewart.

Find the values of a and b such that
$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{a x+b} - 2}{x} = \frac{5}{12}$

This is what I tried with better results.

For $b$:

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{a x+b} - 2}{x} = \frac{5}{12} $$

$$\sqrt[3]{a x+b} - 2 = x\frac{5}{12} $$

$$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}} \sqrt[3]{a x+b} - 2 = \underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}} x\frac{5}{12} $$

$$\sqrt[3]{b} - 2 = 0 $$

$$\sqrt[3]{b}  = 2 $$

$$ b = 8$$

For $a$:

$$a x+8 = (x\frac{5}{12} + 2)^3$$

$$a x+8 = \frac{125 x^3}{1728}+\frac{25 x^2}{24}+5 x+8$$

$$a x = \frac{125 x^3}{1728}+\frac{25 x^2}{24}+5 x$$

$$a = \frac{125 x^2}{1728}+\frac{25 x}{24}+5$$

$$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}} a =\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}  \frac{125 x^2}{1728}+\frac{25 x}{24}+5$$

$$a = 5 $$

But the limit $$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{5x+8} - 2}{x}$$ doens't go to $\frac {5}{12}$.

May someone help.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} = c$ does not imply $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = c\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ if the limit is in indefinite form.

Comment: "But the limit $\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{5x+8} - 2}{x}$ doens't goes to $\frac 5{12}$"  ... uh.... yes, it does..... (use l'hopital)

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti  So it really goes to $\frac{5}{12}$. I didn't compute correctly.

Thanks for the correcting me.

Comment: @fleablood notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about multiplying by the conjugate?
\begin{align*}
(ax+b)^{1/3} - 2 = \frac{ax + b - 8}{(ax+b)^{2/3} + 2(ax+b)^{1/3} + 4}
\end{align*}

Then, if we take $b = 8$, the proposed limit equals
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(ax+b)^{1/3} - 2}{x} & = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\times\frac{ax + b - 8}{(ax+b)^{2/3} + 2(ax+b)^{1/3} + 4} = \frac{a}{12} = \frac{5}{12}
\end{align*}

thence we conclude that $a = 5$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Could you please clarify how to do the conjugate of $\sqrt[3]{a x+b} -2$ ?

Comment: Sure! My answer is based on the identity:

$$w^{3} - z^{3} = (w-z)(w^{2} + wz +z^{2})$$

At your case, $w = (ax+b)^{1/3}$ and $z = 2$.

Comment: I always forget this identity. Now I got it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

As the denominator tends to $0$ the limit can't be finite unless the numerator tends to $0$ are well.  So we must have $\sqrt[3]{a\cdot 0 + b} -2 = 0$ so evaluating the function at $x=0$ will yield indefinite form of $\frac 00$.

So $b=2^3 = 8$.

As the limit is indefinite form we can use L'hopital to calculate

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {(ax+8)^{\frac 13}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}  \frac {\frac 13(ax+8)^{-\frac 23}a}1= \frac {5}{12}$

So as that isn't in indefinite form. we can achieve the limit by evalutation.

So $\frac 13(a\cdot 0+8)^{-\frac 23}a=\frac 5{12}$ and

$\frac 13(a\cdot 0+8)^{-\frac 23}a= \frac a{3\sqrt[3]8^2}= \frac a{12}$

So $\frac a{12} = \frac 5{12}$ and $a=5$

Answer (score 2):

It appears from your working that you had the right idea (at least at the start) in mind and the issue was more related to the use of limit laws.

Let us fix your approach as follows. We have $$\lim_{x\to 0}(\sqrt[3]{ax+b}-2)=\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot\frac {\sqrt [3]{ax+b} - 2}{x}=0\cdot\frac{5}{12}=0$$ which means that $$\sqrt[3]{b}-2=0$$ or $b=8$.

To find $a$ we need a bit more work. Observe that if $a=0$ then the limit in question becomes $0$. Hence $a\neq 0$ and let us put $t=ax+b$ so that $t\to 8$ as $x\to 0$. The limit in question can be written as $$\lim_{t\to 8}\frac{t^{1/3}-8^{1/3}}{t-8}\cdot\frac{t-8}{x}=\frac{5}{12}$$ ie $$\frac{1}{3}\cdot 8^{-2/3}\cdot a =\frac{5}{12}$$ or $a=5$.

To summarize $a=5,b=8$. We have use the standard limit $$\lim_{t\to c} \frac{t^n-c^n} {t-c} =nc^{n-1}$$ (with $c=8,n=1/3$) above.

You should also note that if limit of a function $f(x) $ is $L$ then it does not necessarily hold that $f(x) =L$. This is one crucial mistake which you made while finding $a$.

---

**Food for thought**: Why did I specifically eliminate the option $a=0$? The argument after that probably works without this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the limit

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{(5x+8)^{1/3}-2}{x}$ (of the form $\frac{0}{0}$)

$=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{5.\frac{1}{3}(5x+8)^{-2/3}}{1}$, by L' Hospital's rule (since the limiting value of both numerator and denominator is 0 and the first derivative of the denominator w.r.t. $x$ is non-zero, the rule is applicable).

$=\frac{5}{12}$

Also, letting $y^3=ax+b$, we have the limit $L=\lim\limits_{y\to b^{1/3}}a.\frac{y-2}{y^3-b}$, the denominator tends to $0$, the limit exists iff numerator tends to $0$ too, $\implies b=8$.

Now, $L=\lim\limits_{y\to 2} \frac{a}{y^2+2y+4}=\frac{a}{12}=\frac{5}{12}$ (given) $\implies a=5$.

Comment: I must object to that first line!  The limit does *not* equal $\frac 00$.  It evaluates to the form $\frac 00$ but it certainly does not equal $\frac 00$.  *NOTHING* equals $\frac 00$.  (Not even $\frac 00$ equals $\frac 00$...)

Answer (score 1):

You alos could use the binomial expansion or Taylor series
$$\sqrt[3]{a x+b}=\sqrt[3]{b}+\frac{a x}{3 b^{2/3}}-\frac{a^2 x^2}{9 b^{5/3}}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{a x+b} - 2}{x}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{b}-2}{x}+\frac{a}{3 b^{2/3}}-\frac{a^2 x}{9
   b^{5/3}}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ So, $$\sqrt[3]{b}-2=0 \implies b=8$$
$$\frac{a}{3 b^{2/3}}=\frac{a}{12}=\frac{5}{12}\implies a=5$$